# Youtube API not returning liked videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a problem with the Youtube API, I want to get all my liked videos. 
Using this : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

I find all my playlist but not the liked one.. 
Do you know if it's protected ?

So there is no way i can get my liked videos ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no [search filter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) for Youtube API that says 'get only my liked videos'. But there's a "part" property called 'statistics' that returns how many likes your videos has.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: thats not what i am trying to do. Actually i found a little hack... On the browser you can find the id of your liked platlist and then use it to get the video id, title... But no way to find this id using the api

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of all your "Liked" YouTube videos, regardless of where they are then you need to use:
"Videos : list"

You are using:
"Channels : list"

The URL for "Videos : list" is:
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos`

See documentation at:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#request

There is a sample of Request Parameters for:
list (my liked videos)

An option parameter of:
`myRating=like`

must be included in the URL search string if you are using the REST API.